# C# JsonConvert converts invalid object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have created a simple class:

```
public class TestObject
{
    public TestObject(int id, string name, List<string> list)
    {
        this.Id = id;

        if (name == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        this.Name = name;
        this.List = list;
    }

    [Required]
    public int Id { get; }

    public string Name { get; }

    public List<string> List { get; }
}
```

Which I would like to deserialize and validate if orginal JSON was correct:

```
[Test]
public void MissingIdArgument()
{
    var str = @"{ ""name"": ""aa"" } ";
    Assert.Throws<JsonSerializationException>(() =>
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestObject>(
            str,
            new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                CheckAdditionalContent = true,
                DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include,
                MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error,
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include,

            }));
}
```

I would epxect this test to pass, however it does not. It's not checking if `Id` nor `List` fields even exist in orginal JSON (despite `Id` field being required). Adding some random property to the JSON results in actually throwing exceptions.

How to make `JsonConvert` strict in a sense that this test (as it is) would pass?

To be exact I would expect to:

- `{ id: 1, name: "aa" }` - fail (because no List is defined)
- `{ name: "aa", list: null }` - fail (because no id is defined)
- `{ id: 0, name: "", list: null }` - pass

Comment: How about using a [json schema](http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) to set rules about your json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that you're specifying the required property in a wrong way.

You should **use the [`JsonProperty` attribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) with the [`Required` property](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_Required.htm)** instead of the `Required` attribute.

For example:

```
public class TestObject
{
    // Id has to be present in the JSON
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public int Id { get; }

    // Name is optinional
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Name { get; }

    // List has to be present in the JSON but may be null
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.AllowNull)]
    public List<string> List { get; }
}
```

The `Required` property can be set to a constant from [`Newtonsoft.Json.Required` enum](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Required.htm).

Check the [`JsonPropertyAttribute` class documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) for other configuration possibilities.

You can also check the [example](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyRequired.htm) in the official documentation.

Comment: Although solution from Phill would probably also worked, this one doesn't require any changes in the desiarilizers. Thank you